# ASP.NET customized asp:label view state

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, viewstate

I created a new class for a project. The below is a very slightly simplified version.

```cs
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            LoadText();
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void LoadText()
    {
        this.Text = "This is a test";
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the Text property is not lasting through postbacks. Even if I manually enable viewstate though the tag on the ascx page. Can the custom label tag not have viewstate? I would hate to have to load the text on every page load unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `LoadText();` method call to OnPreRender method

Comment: Perfect. That fixed it. I guess Render is after the viewstate is generated?